# argument for custom model binder MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For the code below, I am wondering how Employee type affects by prefixed [] brackets

```
public ActionResult SaveEmployee([ModelBinder(typeof(MyEmployeeModelBinder))]Employee e, string BtnSubmit)
{
        // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 3):

MyEmployeeModelBinder is a custom model binder, that will execute instead of default model binder in Employee e.

```
public class MyEmployeeModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The Employee type affects `bindingContext` properties in `BindModel()`, like `bindingContext.ModelMetadata` and `bindingContext.ModelType`, that contains information about the model. Take a look at ModelMetaData: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata%28v=vs.108%29